# Sample Project with Spring3.1RC2, Hibernate4.0.0.CR6 and RichFaces4.0.0.Final

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf-2, richfaces

I am looking for a sample projects on Spring3.1RC2, Hibernate4.0.0.CR6 and RichFaces4.0.0.Final. HibernateTemplate is no longer used in latest spring version. So, How to integrate Hibernate4.0 with Spring3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial will help you:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

and this example will help you to integrate Spring with Hibernate without Hibernate Template using AOP Transaction Management.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-transaction-management-in-hibernate/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for quick reply. It is very much helpful to start. The jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example is using Maven to setup the project. I have to set up the project manually in Eclipse.

Comment: This is not an issue. Just create Dynamic web Project and add all required jars to /lib/ folder.